# Multiple upstream proxies failing

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I've been playing around with using Docker to setup a group of web applications that sit behind an Nginx container. I'm using `docker-compose` to manage the different services and all of the individual web service containers work fine but when I try to access them from the Nginx container only one of them works and it's always the first one that I try to access. So if I start up the container group and access app1 then I get the page as expected but if I go to app2 then I get a 50x error. If I restart the group and go to app2 first then I get the page as expected but if I go to app1 I get a 50x error now. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in my Nginx config. Some assistance would be very appreciated.

Here is my Nginx config:

```
upstream app1_backend {
    server app1:8000;
}

upstream app2_backend {
    server app2:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name localhost;

    charset utf-8;

    #location / {
    #    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #    index  index.html index.htm;
    #}

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /static;
    }

    location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass http://app1_backend/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /app2/ {
        proxy_pass http://app2_backend/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

And again I can access the individual applications properly at `http://app1:8000/` and `http://app2:8000/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I had `server_name localhost;`. Changing that to `server_name _;` Fixed this issue.